# Log XCode gdb output to file with .gdbinit

Tags: xcode, logging, gdb

I'm try to redirect gdb output from XCode to a log file for automated testing. I've automated the process of running an app for testing using AppleScript, but I need to be able to see the output. I've tried using the .gdbinit file with

```
set logging file <filepath>
set logging overwrite on
set logging on
```

but I get “warning: Current output protocol does not support redirection” in my log file. A bit of searching for this error message didn't turn up much, besides a mention of a problem with "TUI-mode." If this is the problem, how do I turn off TUI-mode in XCode? If not, what is causing that warning?

Answer (score 1):

As per an answer to this question: [Redirecting debug output from XCode 4 console to a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740344/redirecting-debug-output-from-xcode-4-console-to-a-log-file)

You can use this system default to log Xcode's GDB output to a file:

`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEGDBLogToFile /tmp/logs.txt`

It works for me with Xcode 4.2. Just make sure to restart Xcode after you set that default.

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Now I can use *tail -f | grep xyx* on my logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your `.gdbinit`:

```
set logging redirect off
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. Same message. I tried both "set logging redirect off" and "set logging redirect on" with no noticeable difference...

Comment: I'm guessing xcode does some tricks around `gdb` output, local socket or a pipe probably.