# Writing to files on Mac when running on iOS device attached to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, device

When running an app on an iPhone/iPad via Xcode, is there anyway to open files for writing on the Mac?

I have an app which requires the device to run, so using the simulator isn't an option. I do however need to analyze some of the app's output. Currently I have to write to files on the device, and then manually sync them to the Mac. I'm looking for a way to write my files to the Mac directly.

Comment: Alternatively you could send the file through email (`MFMailComposeViewController`) every time you are writing that file. But the modalview is hindrance to the normal application flow..

Comment: @Aadhira Along the same lines I could perhaps run an ftp server on my Mac and upload the files there. I'd really like though to use an available solution, if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) to stream your log data via Bonjour to the Mac. It has a Mac application that allows you view the data as it is coming in.

For more advanced logging you can also combine NSLogger with the [CocoaLumberJack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) framework using this [connector](https://github.com/steipete/NSLogger-CocoaLumberjack-connector) project.

Comment: Thanks! A note for anyone using NSLogger - Its documentation is a bit outdated, BWToolkit on which it depends doesn't need to be installed separately. Just build and run NSLogger. This is important to note since BWToolkit's documentation is *also* outdated, and it isn't clear how to install it on XCode 4 - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368878/xcode-4-and-bwtoolkit

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best possible solution for your situation probably rests with leveraging the console and NSLog to redirect output to a file - that's an open channel between the device and the Mac you can leverage as long as your running the app from Xcode.

There are a number of questions and answers relating to how to do this - here's one:

[Log XCode gdb output to file with .gdbinit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754680/log-xcode-gdb-output-to-file-with-gdbinit)

This solution assumes that you only need to be doing this when running the app through Xcode, which your question implies.  If you need to write to the Mac when running the app directly on the device (not debugging) you would need to use some type of network file transfer, such as FTP or HTTP.  You could probably whip up a simple HTTP-based logging app that would run on the Mac using:

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer

Then you would just send the content line-by-line to the server.  Many other possible approaches along those lines, and probably an existing Mac-based solution you could leverage.