# How to make xCode stop logging error within a @try @catch

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

All,

I have a chunk of code that runs over a lot of records and in about half of the cases fails (this is ok, some records simply don't have the required data) I put this code in a @try @catch block to make it run smoothly, we try to do our thing, if we fail, we have some default action.

When it fails in the @try block often it is a unrecognized selector error, since it is in the @try block I catch this error, but it still gets logged everytime, even when I don't log from my @catch block. This is very annoying because it clogs up my logging. If I want errors from a @try/@catch logged, I will take care of that in the @catch right?

How can I stop XCode from logging errors in the @try block that are subsequently resolved in the @catch block?

I am using XCode 4.2

Thanks

Comment: You should generally avoid using exceptions (@try/@catch[/@finally]) for flow control in Objective-C. Exceptions carry an unusually large cost (compared to run-times such as JVM or the CLR optimized for exception use). Furthermore, most of the Cocoa frameworks are not exception safe. Thus, throwing an exception through Cocoa framework code is dangerous and will likely cause odd, difficult to diagnose, and catastrophic (think possible data loss) bugs in your app.

Comment: Instead of using exceptions, Cocoa code uses NSError to signal error conditions that are recoverable within the application. Exceptions are used to signal conditions from which your application cannot recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C using exceptions for any normal situation that can appear in a program is a no go. Exceptions are used only for discovering and catching programming errors and terminating gracefully. The problem is that all of the standard libraries (Cocoa, CoreFoundation, C standard library, ...) just are not build to handle exceptions and would fail to clean up resources if exceptions went through them.

Theoretically you could use exceptions if you made sure that you do your memory and other cleanup correctly and do not throw through foreign code. If you use ARC, there's a compiler switch `-fobjc-arc-exceptions` that would help you to get memory management (in your code) right.

Common practice is not to use exceptions at all (other than bugs, for example using `NSAssert`).

Comment: I am aware that it is not the perfect way to go, however it is not an answer to my question/solution to my problem.

Comment: I wrote this answer to make clear that the only clean solution would be to change your architecture. You have to prevent that errors happen. Objective-C can help you with that in many ways but you have to adopt Cocoa's coding patterns.

Comment: You are right, and I will go and change my code to a more proper architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions themselves do not log any message to the console. Neither does Xcode (by default) log any exception throwing.

It's the error catching code that writes the messages before throwing exceptions. NSObject's `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` prints a message when unrecognized selectors are being sent. You cannot turn this off.

Comment: This answer does add some clarity

Answer (score 0):

So you want to see certain log message but not others. How about redirecting the debugger output [into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740344/redirecting-debug-output-from-xcode-4-console-to-a-log-file). On that file  use `grep` or a text editor with nice filtering to scan through message you want to see. Copy & paste from the gdb console into an edtor would do the same trick.